# Is there any way to make padding scale to font size?

Tags: android, view, scale, font-size

I'm used to web design, where I can ensure an element has padding (and other such values) that scales to its current font size, like:

```
button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

**How can I accomplish this in Android?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SP, but it works only for the user side re-size.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm using now :/

Comment: Which I know there is no other ready solution for this problem.